# Trying to sum one field "Count" three time in same query with different where clauses that specify different range of dates?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

```
SELECT DeviceID as "Printer Name",
    (SELECT SUM(Count) WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)as "7 Day Count",
    (SELECT SUM(Count) WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)as "30 Day Count"
 FROM printer_stats.Statistics
 GROUP BY DeviceID
```

This isn't working and would like some input on what to try next.

Comment: Three times? I see only twice.

Comment: are you getting any records for just issuing SELECT SUM(Count) WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY

Comment: Mark - I need to do another date too but haven't worked out the interval yet since it will be for the acedemic year.

Comment: r0ast3d - yes I get the correct data when I just use that select.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN Count ELSE 0 END)`:

```
SELECT
    DeviceID as "Printer Name",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS "7 Day Count",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS "30 Day Count",
FROM printer_stats.Statistics
WHERE DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY DeviceID
```

Comment: Why the additional WHERE after the FROM? Does that need to be there and if so will I need to change it when I use my 3rd where that will be for the acedemic year?

Comment: @user1040277: It's an optmization to prevent an unnecessary full table scan if you have an index on `DATE`. Yes, you will need to change it if you add another count for the entire year.

Comment: It works without the additional WHERE but just asking for reference. Thanks for the quick help!